# Can I access a C# Tuple value in Vue.js code?

Tags: c#, vue.js

So here's the question, can you access returned C# Tuple variables in vue.js?

Example, I have a vue.js function that on a refresh calls a C# action ('GetChartData') which returns a json result to it.

```
    refreshChart: function () {
        var vm = this;
        $.getJSON(window.chartDataRoute, {
            fromDate: (somedate),
            toDate: (somedate)
        }).done(function (data) {
            vm.chartData = data;
        });
    },
```

So the json result of the C# function gets passed as a ContentResult type into vm.chartData in the vue.js code. Here's the C# function:

```cs
    public ContentResult GetChartData(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
    {
        var pageStats = (go away and get some data);
        var chartModel = ChartHelpers.GetMainChartModel(chartPeriod, pageStats);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartModel, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
        return new ContentResult { Content = json, ContentType = "application/json" };
    }
```

All pretty straighforward, but I need to return two new fields to the vue.js function, and I really don't want to get involved with rewriting the json result as the results are used in a graph function that is beyond the scope of what I'm trying to do.

So, can I convert the function to a Tuple and pass two extra int values and then access them in the vue.js code? Like this:

```cs
    public Tuple<ContentResult,int,int> GetChartData(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
    {
        var pageStats = (go away and get some data);

        var totalClicks = (an int number);
        var totalViews = (an int number);

        var chartModel = ChartHelpers.GetMainChartModel(chartPeriod, pageStats);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartModel, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });

        // Can I return the extra data in a Tuple?
        return Tuple.Create(new ContentResult { Content = json, ContentType = "application/json" }, totalClicks, totalViews);
    }
```

However, this breaks the vue.js, as I suppose 'data' is now different and so the graphs don't work. So I'd need to be able to assign the ContentResult to data (as it is now), **and** the two extra ints somehow.

If I can't do it like this then can I do it another way that doesn't involve rewriting any of the vue.js in depth? One of problems is that I'm a bit of a vue.js novice...

Comment: No - the `ContentResult` represents what gets returned in the HTTP response. If you want data to be included in the HTTP response, that's where it needs to go. It really sounds like you should be changing your chart model to include the extra values.

Comment: Thanks, that's my last resort - I really don't have the time to get stuck in that! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the C# function twice one for chartdata and other for the other two properties.
you also need to pass some Identifier for which the C# function get called either for chartdata or other two properties.

Comment: This is actually the solution I just implemented as I was waiting for any suggestions! I actually made a new function for the totals but you're right, I could have just kept a single one. My main issue with this is that I call the stats-generating function three times, which annoys me as a programmer as it's incredibly wasteful, SQL intensive, and inelegant... If I don't get any other solutions I'll mark this as the answer as it is so far what I'm doing! But ideally, a better way will be found :)

Comment: @Ralpharama: You already know the better way: return a single response containing all the data. There are multiple ways of doing that, including adding the two extra data points into the existing data structure, or by create a new "higher level" data structure with the existing value as one property, and the two new values as the other two properties.

Comment: Thanks @jon-skeet, the better way is just too complex and involved. I imagine I could add a higher-level wrapping, or add two extra data points into the structure, but altering the code that generates the model for serialization, and the models is just too much for this minor edit I've been asked to do. Hack it is.